# How to set internal border around a CSS Grid items?

Tags: html, css

So far I have tried like this. I want to set a border around the grid elements inside the grid. Is there any way to do it?

```css
.grid{
            background: cornflowerblue;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 10px;
            height: 500px;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
            grid-template-rows: 60px 60px 60px;
            grid-gap: 30px 10px;
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: center;

        }
        .item{
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            line-height: 32px;
            letter-spacing: 5px;
            font-weight: bold;
            border: 1px solid white;
            text-align: center;
            display: grid;
            align-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item">A1</div>
    <div class="item">A2</div>
    <div class="item">A3</div>
    <div class="item">A4</div>
    <div class="item">A5</div>
    <div class="item">A6</div>
    <div class="item">A7</div>
    <div class="item">A8</div>
    <div class="item">A9</div>
</div>
```

But I want a border around the items like shown in the image.
[image]

Comment: As an added hint - learn the css keywords and how to use the debug features in browsers. You can then experiment with setting parameters on the fly to figure out what works before putting them into the css sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give higher outline, if you want a very big offset

```
.subgrid {
    outline-offset: 50px;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.subgrid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 60px 60px;
  grid-gap: 30px 10px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  outline-offset: 50px;
}

.item {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="subgrid">
    <div class="item">A1</div>
    <div class="item">A2</div>
    <div class="item">A3</div>
    <div class="item">A4</div>
    <div class="item">A5</div>
    <div class="item">A6</div>
    <div class="item">A7</div>
    <div class="item">A8</div>
    <div class="item">A9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad you like it, Welcome

Answer (score 0):

Create a new div around and

```
.newDiv {
 border: 5px solid red;
}
```